# Standard notation for $X-E[X|Y]$

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request, notation, schur-complement

Is there standard notation for a random variable of the form $X-E[X|Y]$?

Comment: This quantity commonly appears when analyzing jointly-multivariate-normal $X,Y$. Currently I am writing it as "$(X|Y)$" which is awkward but corresponds well to the usual conditional covariance matrix notation $\operatorname{var}(X|Y)$.

Comment: $(X|Y)$ is a bit confusing with $\int_{\Omega} X\overline{Y} dP$ or $\text{Cov}(X, Y)$

Comment: Yes, it looks like an inner product which is a very good example of why it is not the right choice.

Comment: You can always say that $M(X, Y) = X-E[X|Y]$ and never mention it again. Or a different letter if this bothers you. If $X$ and $Y$ are fixed, you can just call it $M$.

Comment: My guess is that the notation $(X|Y)$ will either lead to significant errors later, or will just confuse readers.

Comment: How about $\mathbb{E}_\perp(X|Y)$